# How to properly get an element with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and trying to parse a simple HTML. However, one thing stops me: for example, I have this html:

```html
<div class = "quote">
<div class = "whatever"> 
some unnecessary text here 
</div>
<div class = "text">
Here's the desired text!
</div>
</div>
```

I need to extract text from second div (text). This way I get it:

`print repr(link.find('div').findNextSibling())`

However, this returns the whole div (with "div" word): `<div class="text">Here's the desired text!</div>`

And I don't know how to get text only.

- Adding `.text` results in `\u043a\u0430\u043a \u0440\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0431` strings\
- Adding `.strings` returns `"None"`
- Adding `.string` returns both `"None"` and `\u042f\u0445\u0438\u043a\u043e - \u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438\`

Maybe there's something wrong with `repr`

P.S. I need to save tags inside `div` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply search the `<div>` element based in its `class` attribute? Something like the following seems to work for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class = "quote">
<div class = "whatever"> 
some unnecessary text here 
</div>
<div class = "text">
Here's the desired text!
</div>
</div>'''


link = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
print link.find('div', class_="text").text.strip()
```

It yields:

```
Here's the desired text!
```

Comment: wow, I didn't know that `class_` works! (tried `class`, but it's reserved name)

Comment: @Kondra007: Adapt it to the real world. You first have to download the `html` code and parse it with `BeautifulSoup`, and the class attribute could be different.

Comment: Well, I found out that I should use `find('div', { "class" : "text"})` instead. However, `text.strip()` removes all internal tags

Comment: @Kondra007: I guess you are using `BeautifulSoup3`. Mine is `BeautifulSoup4`. Some things may be different.